# What is the purpose/function of these variable assignments in assembly?

Tags: assembly, syntax

```
var_30= qword ptr -30h
var_24= dword ptr -24h
var_20= dword ptr -20h
var_1C= dword ptr -1Ch
var_18= dword ptr -18h
var_14= dword ptr -14h
var_10= dword ptr -10h
var_8= qword ptr -8
```

After disassembling a binary, I found this at the very top of the source file. There was nothing else above it, I am fairly certain it has something to do with command line input, but I am not sure. So does it have something to do with command line input. Also, I was wondering exactly what the equal and minus signs have to do with assigning the variable.

Comment: The disassembler is essentially trying to locate "local variables" which it can access via offsets from the frame pointer. These "variables" will be used somewhere else in your disassembly with code such as `[esp+20h+var_14]`, etc. ". "does it have something to do with command line input" - impossible to tell without seeing the context around where these are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the listing more understandable some disassemblers try to interpret common code patterns.

One of such pattern is to access local variables with a negative offset with respect to the [frame pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) but this may also be triggered by code that handles data in the stack without a frame pointer.

This purposefully unoptimized 32-bit program<sup>1</sup> computes the n-th triangular number using a frame-pointer and two local vars:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 08h

push ebx


mov DWORD PTR [ebp-04h], 1
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-08h], 0

_loop:
 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp-04h]
 cmp ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+08h]
  ja _end

 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp-04h]
 add DWORD PTR [ebp-08h], ebx

 inc DWORD PTR [ebp-04h]
jmp _loop


_end:
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-08h]

pop ebx

add esp, 08h

pop ebp
ret 04h
```

<sup>1</sup> The program structure, the layout of the loop and the usage of local variables is exaggerated for didactic purpose.

The disassembler sees the accesses to `[ebp-xx]` and gives them a name:

```
;var_8 = DWORD PTR -8
;var_4 = DWORD PTR -4
;par_8 = DWORD PTR 8
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 08h

push ebx


mov DWORD PTR [ebp+var_4], 1
mov DWORD PTR [ebp+var_8], 0

_loop:
 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+var_4]
 cmp ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+par_8]
  ja _end

 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+var_4]
 add DWORD PTR [ebp+var_8], ebx

 inc DWORD PTR [ebp+var_4]
jmp _loop


_end:
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+var_8]
pop ebx

add esp, 08h

pop ebp
ret 04h
```

Usually, one can rename these var as they go through the reverse engineering:

```
;sum = DWORD PTR -8
;i = DWORD PTR -4
;n = DWORD PTR 8
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 08h

push ebx


mov DWORD PTR [ebp+i], 1               ;Start from i=1...
mov DWORD PTR [ebp+sum], 0             ;Result is 0 initially

_loop:
 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+i]            
 cmp ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+n]
  ja _end                               ;... to i <= n

 mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+i]
 add DWORD PTR [ebp+sum], ebx           ;sum += i

 inc DWORD PTR [ebp+i]                  ;i++
jmp _loop


_end:
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+sum]
pop ebx

add esp, 08h

pop ebp
ret 04h
```